# Using Salesforce style/css for table sort order

Tags: css, pageblocktable, images, styleclass

I've created a custom page which apes the standard related list layout.

I want to use the same CSS styling to indicate that sorting is on a particular column. This is what it looks like on a standard related list page:

[image: related list table header]

Does anyone know how I can make my table look like the standard one, particularly with the sort arrow icons?

Comment: It's not supported in an out-of-the-box way. I'd be interested to see if anyone has hacked a way to do this.

Comment: I've tried, and it works to a small extent, but it's a reverse engineering guessing game. IMO CSS should be supported in the same way that regular code is supported.